# MVC - why code after ajax.beginform being executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

Form for AJAX call:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("RefineSearchResults", "Search", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "resultsSec" }))
{
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<div id="resultsSec"></div>
}
```

after form tag:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "NewsLetter", new { area = "" });}
```

but, it throws exception on second piece of code when posted back although it's not supposed to be execued because it's an AJAX call and it's outside the Ajax form.

Exception message:

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Can anyone please tell me what's going wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated my question with exception message.

Comment: Looks like a you have a endless loop - you need to show your views and the POST method. And what do you mean _"it's not supposed to be executed"_? `Html.RenderAction()` is executed when the page is first rendered.

Comment: Yes of course it's executed when page is rendered first time but, why it's rendered on AJAX call. Let me show you view code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops!!! My mistake!
Actually, I was returning the main view again that's why code that wasn't supposed to be rendered was being rendered.

Now I have added the view code that was to be refereshed through Ajax.BeginForm() to a partial view.

My openion:

> You should apply Ajax form on partial view preferably because from
>   controller when you return a view then the target view have to be rendered
>   again (it's ok when you have to show only a string through Content()
>   method.)

So, refreshing the partial view through Ajax form would be an ideal way to use Ajax.BeginForm() in my humble openion.